# Add new request parameter to a SlingHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, aem, servlet-filters, sling

I have a use case where I need to add a custom request parameter to an intercepted request in a sling servlet filter.

Since the query param map is immutable, I wrapped the request in a SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper, and override the getRequestParameterMap the params I need to add. However I am stuck, and I am not able to create the new param.
The param should be of type **Map<String, RequestParameter[]>** But since RequestParameter is abstract I do not know how to instantiate a new instance.

Any help please ???

Here is the code of my filter :

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            if(!(request instanceof SlingHttpServletRequest) && !(response instanceof SlingHttpServletResponse)) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
            }

            final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
            final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (SlingHttpServletResponse) response;
            TreeMap<String, RequestParameter[]> newParam = new TreeMap<>();

            if(!isEmpty(slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectors())) {
                    String selector = slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectorString();
                    //Map param = slingRequest.getParameterMap();
                    BrandSlingWrappedRequest requestWrapper = new BrandSlingWrappedRequest(slingRequest, newParam);
            } else {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
    }
```

And here is the code of my request wrapper :

```
public class BrandSlingWrappedRequest extends SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper {

private final Map<String, RequestParameter[]> modifiableParameters;
private Map<String, RequestParameter[]> allParameters = null;

public BrandSlingWrappedRequest(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final Map<String, RequestParameter[]> additionalParams) {
    super(request);
    modifiableParameters = new TreeMap<>();
    modifiableParameters.putAll(additionalParams);
}

@Override
public RequestParameterMap getRequestParameterMap()
{
    if (allParameters == null)
    {
        allParameters = new TreeMap<>();
        allParameters.putAll(super.getRequestParameterMap());
        allParameters.putAll(modifiableParameters);
    }
    return (RequestParameterMap) allParameters;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why a request parameter and not a request attribute. If all you need is pass some context down the code flow request attribute could be a readily available solution.

Comment: Request attribute wont work in my case. The params are being processed by third party code That I can not change. And I need to add a new param in my case to be taken into account by the third party code